# template for list view with system categories

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have an extbase extension (TYPO3 7) with a simple model of a contact person.
The person has a name and a picture.

So far this is clear.

But every Person has a category (e.g. where he works. Office, Marketing etc.)

Therefor i use the system categories, as described here:
[https://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3_6.0#Adding_categories_to_own_models_without_using_Extension_Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hto6.jpg)

When creating a person via web > list, i can assign a category.

Now the question for templating:
If i debug my contact person, i get the output like screen below.

[image]

I want to have a list where every category (headline) is shown with it's contact persons.

How to do this?
Is the logic for this only in the template or also in the controller?

Has anybody an example for this?

Best regards
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the required logic you need is possible with Fluid with using the GroupedFor ViewHelper and many others. Because a person can have multiple categories this would become a huge nesting of Viewhelpers so I can not recommend to use Fluid for this even if its possible. This kind of logics belong to the controllers, models and repositories.

There are multiple ways to solve this logic. **Here is an example how to realize this in the controller...**

Controller:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $categoryRespoitory = NULL;

/**
 * action list
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction()
{
    $allCategories = $this->categoryRespoitory->findAll();
    $categoriesWithContacts = [];
    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category $category */
    foreach($allCategories as $category) {
        $contactsInCategory= $this->contactRepository->findByCategory($category);
        if($contactsInCategory->count()>0) {
            $categoriesWithContacts[] = [
                'category' => $category,
                'contacts' => $contactsInCategory
            ];
        }
    }
    $this->view->assignMultiple([
       'categoriesWithContacts' => $categoriesWithContacts
    ]);
}
```

Injecting the CategoryRespository will required clearing cache in install tool or reinstalling the extension.

**Maybe** you need this function in your ContactRepository:

```
/**
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category $category
 * @return array|\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryResultInterface
 */
public function findByCategory(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category $category) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    return $query->matching($query->contains('categories', $category))->execute();
}
```

Then in Fluid you can do something like this:

```
<f:for each="{categoriesWithContacts}" as="categoryWithContact">
    {categoryWithContact.category.title}
    <f:for each="{categoryWithContact.contacts}" as="contact">
        {contact.name}
    </f:for>
</f:for>
```